# Como mostrar/esconder o elemento com Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou dando cabeçadas nesse problema e não consigo resolver, alguém poderia me mostrar o erro e explicar o por que não está dando certo dessa forma? Se possível, a solução também.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    
   $("button").click(function() {
        
        if(this) {
            $("p").hide()
        }
        else {
            $("p").show()
        }
   
   })
   


})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>


<button>Mostrar/Esconder</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aqui `if(this) {` sempre será avaliado como `true` troque por `if($("p:visible").length > 0) {`

Comment: poderia explicar qual elemento sera ocultado e qual ponto não encontrou solução,para referencias futuras... presumo que sejam todas a tag <p> ...</p> ???

Answer (score -2):

Não precisa de Jquery para fazer isso.

usando JS você consegue fazer uma forma mais facil.

```
let btn = document.getElementById('idBotao');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
let tag = document.querySelectorAll('p')
for(i = 0; tag.length < i; i++){
tag[i].classList.toggle('esconder')}
})
```

cria uma classe para esconder o conteudo ou para exibir, nesse caso eu estou citando uma para esconder

```
p.esconder{
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0; }
p:not(.esconder){
visibility: unset;
opacity: 1;}
```